# How can I syncronize a non-domain server to a domain-controller's clock?

Tags: domain-controller, time, windows-server-2000, time-synchronization

Is it possible to configure a Windows Server 2000 OS to synchronize it's clock to a domain controller **if it's not on the domain**?  If so, how would I go about doing that?

Just to be clear:

- I can't join the machine to the domain.
- The Windows Time service is running on the Server 2000 box.
- All other servers and workstations properly sync their time to the domain controller already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/120944

Comment: This'll do the trick. I should also add that this is only valid for Windows 2000 and older servers, as they implemented the cut-down time protocol sNTP. For Windows 2003 and XP upwards, net time is deprecated and w32tm is the tool you'll need to use, as these OS' implement a fully compliant NTP server/client service.

Comment: Man I typed out my answer all nice and neat and then forgot to press the Submit button. +1 for providing a backup link though.

Comment: Actually, the Net Time command does work in W2K3 and W2K8.

Answer (score 2):

`NET TIME \\servername /SET` (where `servername` is a DC)

Answer (score 0):

This command works, but if you're not yet joined to the domain, you need to put in an IP address in place of "servername".

Comment: Which command? Did you forget something in your answer?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a comment to Mark Henderson's answer